# The kernel of nilpotent Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let V be an n-dimensional complex vector space, and let T: V-V be a linear transformation.

For i > 0, let $K_i = kerT^i$($T^0$ means the identity transformation). Show that for each i, $K_i$ ⊆$ K_{i+1}$, and deduce that there exists a non-negative integer r such that $K_r = K_{r+1}$. Prove that $K_r= K_{r+j}$ for all j ≥ 1. Hence, or otherwise, show that $V = K_r ⊕ T^r(V)$.

Suppose that the only eigenvalues of T are $0$ and $λ$, where λ$\neq$0.
Let W = $T^r(V)$, where r satisfies $kerT^r=kerT^{r+1}$. Show that T(W) $⊆$ W, and that the restriction of T to W has λ as its only eigenvalue. Let S denote the restriction of $(T − λI)$ to W. Show that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of S. By applying (i) with S, W in place of T, V , show that $S^m(W) = 0$ for some m.

I know how to show $K_i$ ⊆$ K_{i+1}$ and since the dimension of the subspace of V is bounded by n, it can not increase infinitely. we must have $K_r$=$K_{r+1}$ at some r. But how to rigidly show that $K_r= K_{r+j}$ and the direct sum $V = K_r ⊕ T^r(V)$(I think it is the projection direct sum, can I just show V=ker$⊕$img?).

Can anyone give a hint on how to show $T^{r+1}(v)$ $⊆$  $T^r(v)$ And why the problem relates to the eigenvalue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $v \in T^{r+1}(V)$. Then there is $u \in V$ such that $v=T^{r+1}(u)$.

But then $v=T^r(T(u)) \in T^r(V)$.